# jquery find radio button in table

Tags: jquery, radio-button, selection

I am trying to find all radio buttons contained in a TR with a specific class name. 
Once I have found the radio inputs (they are a simple yes/no choice), I must set the radio to No.

Here is sample HTML:

```
<tr class="paramfield263 type0param  conditionalhidden">
<td class="paramlist_key"><span>I certify that my organization is exempt from GST and PST</span></td>
<td class="paramlist_value"><span class=" rsvpparam rsvpparam0 rsvp_field263">
    <input type="radio" value="1" id="paramsfield2631" name="params[field263]">
    <label for="paramsfield2631">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="0" id="paramsfield2630" name="params[field263]">
    <label for="paramsfield2630">No</label></span>
</td>
</tr>
```

Here is what ive got so far(using noConflict mode):

```
if (jQuery("tr").hasClass('conditionalhidden')){
        if (jQuery("tr td span").hasClass('rsvpparam0')){
            //found radios inside span with correct class
            //Now need to set the radio choice to No


        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery("table input[val='no']").attr("checked", true)
```

So in the example you provided you'd want something like:

```
jQuery(".conditionalhidden .rsvpparam0 input[val='no']").attr("checked", true);
```

*note: this is assuming you need all of these classes to accurately find the correct inputs.*

Comment: Wont that set all inputs within the table to NO? I need it to set only the input it finds in the span with the appropriate class

Comment: Updated to mirror your example better.

Comment: Yes, you'd want to select like this: jQuery(".conditionalhidden input[val='no']").attr...

Comment: Thanks, also how could I make this trigger when either input I provided above is changed?

Comment: Wrap it in a jQuery("table input[type='radio']).change() event handler. More info can be found in the jQuery docs here: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate way:

```
$('tr.conditionalhidden td span.rsvpparam0 input[type="radio"]#paramsfield2630').attr("checked", true)
```

The easy way (but also depends on your implementation)

```
$('#paramsfield2631').attr("checked", true)
```

these IDs seem to be generated.. so maybe a good option is to use `input:last` to just select the first input, but make sure it is preceded by the appropriate selectors